# JPA Nullable JoinColumn

Tags: jpa, join, nullable

I have an entity:

```
public class Foo {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   private String username;

   @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "ParentID", nullable = true)
   private Foo parent;

   // other fields
}
```

With this kind of relationship, each Foo object has a parent, except the first Foo instance in the DB which has a NULL ParentID. When i try to create a query via criteria api and try to search for the first Foo object (null parent id) using any of it's properties (ID, username etc..), i get a:

```
javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
```

How should the JoinColumn be implemented in this case? How should i get the first Foo object in the DB which has a null parent ID?

Thanks

Updated September 28 2011

What i am trying to achieve is to look lookfor all Foos with a username starting in "foo" and would like to use as separate object being returned then:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder;
CriteriaQuery<FooDto> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(FooDto.class);
Root<Foo> foo = criteriaQuery.from(Foo.class);

criteriaQuery.multiselect(foo.get("id"), foo.get("username"), foo.get("parent").get("username"), foo.get("property1")
//other selected properties);

Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
predicate = criteriaBuilder.and(predicate, criteriaBuilder.like(foo.get("username").as(String.class), criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class, "username")));
// other criteria

criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

TypedQuery<FooDto> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
typedQuery.setParameter("username", "foo%");
// other parameters

// return result
```

assuming that the usernames are foo1, foo2 and foo3 wherein foo1 has a null parent, the result set will only return foo2 and foo3 even if the foo1 has a username that starts with the specified predicate.
and also searching for foo1 alone will throw a

```
javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
```

Is there a way to still include foo1 with the rest of the results? or foo1 will always be a special case since i have to add a criteria specifying that the parent is null? Or perhaps ai have missed an option in the joinColumn to do so.

Thanks

**UPDATED Thu Sep 29 13:03:41 PHT 2011**
@mikku
I have updated the criteria part of the post above (property1), because i think this is the part that is responsible for foo1 not to be included in the Result Set.

Here's a partial view of the generated query from the logs:

```
select 
    foo.id as id, 
    foo.username as username, 
    foo.password as password, 
    foo.ParentID as parentId, 
    foo_.username as parentUsername, 
    foo.SiteID as siteId, 
from FOO_table foo, FOO_table foo_ cross join Sites site2_ 
where foo.ParentID=foo_.id and foo.SiteID=site2_.id and 1=1 
and foo.username=? and site2_.remoteKey=? limit ?
```

and this wont return Foo1, obviously because username value is from foo_ which is why my original question is 'how should i get to Foo1'.

On the part that i have commented that ill use SelectCase and mix it up with your first reply, what i did is to add this part on the multiselect:

```
criteriaBuilder
   .selectCase()
      .when(criteriaBuilder.isNotNull(agent.get("parent")), agent.get("parent").get("username"))
      .otherwise(criteriaBuilder.literal("")),
```

replacing the

```
foo.get("parent").get("username")
```

However this wont be able to get Foo1 as well. My Last resort though inefficient would probably check if the parameters are of Foo1 and create a criteriaQuery specifying a literal value for username, and using the default query otherwise.

Suggestions/alternatives are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

In your edited question nullable joincolumn is not problem - missing construction of FooDto, multiselect etc are. You can achieve your goal with following:

Querying:

```
    /**
     * Example data:
     * FOO
     * |id|username|property1|parentid|
     * | 1| foo    |  someval|    null|<= in result
     * | 2| fooBoo | someval2|       1|<= in result
     * | 3|somename| someval3|    null|
     */
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<FooDto> c = cb.createQuery(FooDto.class);
    Root<Foo> fooRoot = c.from(Foo.class);
    Predicate predicate = cb.like(fooRoot.get("username").as(String.class),
                                  cb.parameter(String.class, "usernameParam"));

    c.select(
            cb.construct(FooDto.class,
                         fooRoot.get("id"),
                         fooRoot.get("username"),
                         fooRoot.get("property1")))
    .where(predicate);

    TypedQuery<FooDto> fooQuery = em.createQuery(c);
    fooQuery.setParameter("usernameParam", "foo%");

    List<FooDto> results = fooQuery.getResultList();
```

Object to hold data:

```
public class FooDto {
    private final long id;
    private final String userName;
    private final String property1;
    //you need constructor that matches to type and order of arguments in cb.construct
    public FooDto(long id, String userName, String property1) {
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.property1 = property1;
    }

    public long getId() { return id; }
    public String getUserName() { return userName; }
    public String getProperty1() { return property1; }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. sorry for the typo as i forgot to put the Entity annotation on the post. By the way based on your recommended answer i assume i will need to have a separate query for the case of the first foo because it has a null parent? i have updated my posted question with what i hope to achieve.
Thanks

Comment: You don't need special case. It was answer to your original question: "How should i get the first Foo object in the DB which has a null parent ID?"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. & apologies for i have forgotten to include the FooDto constructor which i already have + (multiselect stated above IS WORKING given that the constructor of the same param type and order exist,& because the type of c has already been specified as a FooDto). However since my follow up question is:
Is there a way to still include foo1 with the rest of the results? or foo1 will always be a special case since i have to add a criteria specifying that the parent is null? 
i ended up mixing your first answer to specify a null criteria chained in a select case.

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, this one query selects also foo1. There is nothing special with foo1, except one of it's fields is null. You code from this answer directly without select cases. If it doesn't work to you, then the problem is somewhere else than in query. Maybe libraries, other connected part of program, etc.

Comment: i mentioned on my original post that foo1 has a null parent id on the db therefore a null parent property and this is the thing i think is causing why foo1 will never be included in the result set. in this case property1 might refer to FooDto.parent.id. ill include the generated query from the logs on the original post..
Thanks again.